# How to measure the execution time of C math.h library functions?

Tags: c++, c, time

By using `time.h` header, I'm getting execution time of `sqrt()` as 2 nanoseconds (with the `gcc` command in a Linux terminal) and 44 nanoseconds (with the `g++` command in Ubuntu terminal). Can anyone tell me any other method to measure the execution time of the `math.h` library functions?

Below is the code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{

    time_t begin,end; // time_t is a datatype to store time values.
    time (&begin); // note time before execution
    for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++)  //using for loop till 10^9 times to make the execution time in nanoseconds
    {
        cbrt(9999999);  // calling the cube root function from math library
    }
    time (&end); // note time after execution
    double difference = difftime (end,begin);
    printf ("time taken for function() %.2lf in Nanoseconds.\n", difference );
    printf(" cube root is :%f \t",cbrt(9999999));

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
by using **gcc**: time taken for function() 2.00 seconds.
                  cube root is :215.443462
by using **g++**: time taken for function() 44.00 in Nanoseconds.
                  cube root is:215.443462
```

[Linux terminal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kENG8.png)

<sup>*Give or take the length of the prompt:*</sup>

```
$ g++ t1.c
$ ./a.out
time taken for function() 44.00 in Nanoseconds.
 cube root is :215.443462
$ gcc t1.c
$ ./a.out
time taken for function() 2.00 in Nanoseconds.
 cube root is :215.443462
$
```

Comment: The compiler can optimize the entire loop away.  You're using `cbrt()`, not `sqrt()` as your spiel claims.  You're calling it with the same value each time — which the compiler can evaluate at compile time.  And you are doing nothing with the result, so the compiler can discard that constant value.  So, you're measuring the time it takes to call `time()` twice.  And `time()` normally (on Linux, always) has 1 second granularity.  Any difference is in whole seconds.  Did you compile with the same optimization on both?  Same base version for `gcc` and `g++`?  Measuring performance is hard!

Comment: So, you probably need to do something like sum the cube roots of the numbers from one to one billion, and then print that sum at the end.  That prevents the compiler from pre-computing the result.  Remember to include `-O3` or thereabouts (`-O` at least) in the compiler options.  I suppose since you are doing one billion loops, you can claim that the time in seconds represents the number of nanoseconds for a single iteration — my bad on discounting that.  But it is crucial to make sure that the compiler does what you expect — calling the function a billion times.

Comment: I note that when I compile your code (saved in `tm71.c` — with some additions) with my default options, GCC 9.3.0 (and probably earlier versions too) complains (giving an error because I told it to): `gcc -O3 -g -I../inc    -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes tm71.c -o tm71 -L../lib  -lsoq` ——
`tm71.c: In function ‘main’:` —
`tm71.c:22:9: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]` —
   `22 |         cbrt(9999999);`

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I am using the same version (7.5.0) for both gcc and g++ but I'm getting different results. Can you please suggest me some method of finding the execution time of math library functions? Actually, I have made certain math library functions by myself and I just want to compare the execution time of my math functions with the math.h library functions.

Answer (score 1):

> how to measure the execution time of c math.h library functions?

C compilers are often allowed to *analyze* well known standard library functions and replace such fix code like `cbrt(9999999);` with `215.443462...`.  Further, since dropping the function in the loop does not affect the *function* of the code, that loop may be optimized out.

Use of `volatile` prevents much of this as the compiler cannot assume no impact when the function is replaced, removed.

```
for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
    // cbrt(9999999);
    volatile double x = 9999999.0;
    volatile double y = cbrt(x);
}
```

---

The granularity of `time()` is often only 1 second and if the billion loops only results in a few seconds, consider more loops.

---

Code could use below to factor out the loop overhead.

```
time_t begin,middle,end;
time (&begin);
for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
    volatile double x = 9999999.0;
    volatile double y = x;
}
time (&middle);
for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
    volatile double x = 9999999.0;
    volatile double y = cbrt(x);
}
time (&end);
double difference = difftime(end,middle) - difftime(middle,begin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Timing code is an art, and one part of the art is making sure that the compiler doesn't optimize your code away.  For standard library functions, the compiler may well be aware of what it is/does and be able to evaluate a constant at compile time.  In your example, the call `cbrt(9999999);` gives two opportunities for optimization.  The value from `cbrt()` can be evaluated at compile-time because the argument is a constant.  Secondly, the return value is not used, and the standard function has no side-effects, so the compiler can drop it altogether.  You can avoid those problems by capturing the result (for example, by evaluating the sum of the cube roots from 0 to one billion (minus one) and printing that value after the timing code.

#### `tm97.c`

When I compiled your code, shorn of comments, I got:

```
$ cat tm97.c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t begin, end;
    time(&begin);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        cbrt(9999999);
    }
    time(&end);
    double difference = difftime(end, begin);
    printf("time taken for function() %.2lf in Nanoseconds.\n", difference );
    printf(" cube root is :%f \t", cbrt(9999999));

    return 0;
}
$ make tm97
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes         tm97.c -o tm97 -L../lib -lsoq 
tm97.c: In function ‘main’:
tm97.c:11:9: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
   11 |         cbrt(9999999);
      |         ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
rmk: error code 1
$
```

I'm using GCC 9.3.0 on a 2017 MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with XCode 11.3.1 (11C504) and GCC 9.3.0 — XCode 11.4 requires Catalina 10.15.2, but work hasn't got around organizing support for that, yet.  Interestingly, when the same code is compiled by `g++`, it compiles without warnings (errors):

```
$ ln -s tm97.c tm89.cpp
make tm89 SXXFLAGS=-std=c++17 CXX=g++
g++ -O3 -g  -I../inc -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -L../lib tm89.cpp -lsoq -o tm89
$
```

I routinely use some timing code that is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `timer.c` and `timer.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  The code is only compiled as C code in my library, so I created a simple wrapper header, `timer2.h`, so that the programs below could use `#include "timer2.h"` and it would work OK with both C and C++ compilations:

```
#ifndef TIMER2_H_INCLUDED
#define TIMER2_H_INCLUDED

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include "timer.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* TIMER2_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### `tm29.cpp` and `tm31.c`

This code uses the `sqrt()` function for testing.  It accumulates the sum of the square roots.  It uses the timing code from `timer.h`/`timer.c` around your timing code — type `Clock` and functions `clk_init()`, `clk_start()`, `clk_stop()`, and `clk_elapsed_us()` to evaluate the elapsed time in microseconds between when the clock was started and last stopped.

The source code can be compiled by either a C compiler or a C++ compiler.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "timer2.h"

int main(void)
{
    time_t begin, end;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i;
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    time(&begin);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        sum += sqrt(i);
    }
    time(&end);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    double difference = difftime(end, begin);
    char buffer[32];
    printf("Time taken for sqrt() is %.2lf nanoseconds (%s ns).\n",
           difference, clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
    printf("Sum of square roots from 0 to %d is: %f\n", i, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

#### `tm41.c` and `tm43.cpp`

This code is almost identical to the previous code, but the tested function is the `cbrt()` (cube root) function.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "timer2.h"

int main(void)
{
    time_t begin, end;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i;
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    time(&begin);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        sum += cbrt(i);
    }
    time(&end);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    double difference = difftime(end, begin);
    char buffer[32];
    printf("Time taken for cbrt() is %.2lf nanoseconds (%s ns).\n",
           difference, clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
    printf("Sum of cube roots from 0 to %d is: %f\n", i, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

#### `tm59.c` and `tm61.c`

This code uses `fabs()` instead of either `sqrt()` or `cbrt()`.  It's still a function call, but it might be inlined.  It invokes the conversion from `int` to `double` explicitly; without that cast, GCC complains that it should be using the integer `abs()` function instead.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "timer2.h"

int main(void)
{
    time_t begin, end;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i;
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    time(&begin);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        sum += fabs((double)i);
    }
    time(&end);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    double difference = difftime(end, begin);
    char buffer[32];
    printf("Time taken for fabs() is %.2lf nanoseconds (%s ns).\n",
           difference, clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
    printf("Sum of absolute values from 0 to %d is: %f\n", i, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

#### `tm73.cpp`

This file uses the original code with my timing wrapper code too.  The C version doesn't compile — the C++ version does:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "timer2.h"

int main(void)
{
    time_t begin, end;
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    time(&begin);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        cbrt(9999999);
    }
    time(&end);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    double difference = difftime(end, begin);
    char buffer[32];
    printf("Time taken for cbrt() is %.2lf nanoseconds (%s ns).\n",
           difference, clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
    printf("Cube root is: %f\n", cbrt(9999999));

    return 0;
}
```

#### Timing

Using a command `timecmd` which reports start and stop time, and PID, of programs as well as the timing code built into the various commands (it's a variant on the theme of the `time` command), I got the following results.  (`rmk` is just an alternative implementation of `make`.)

```
$ for prog in tm29 tm31 tm41 tm43 tm59 tm61 tm73
> do rmk $prog && timecmd -ur -- $prog
> done
g++ -O3 -g -I../inc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror tm29.cpp -o tm29 -L../lib -lsoq 
2020-03-28 08:47:50.040227 [PID 19076] tm29
Time taken for sqrt() is 1.00 nanoseconds (1.700296 ns).
Sum of square roots from 0 to 1000000000 is: 21081851051977.781250
2020-03-28 08:47:51.747494 [PID 19076; status 0x0000]  -  1.707267s  -  tm29
gcc -O3 -g -I../inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes tm31.c -o tm31 -L../lib -lsoq 
2020-03-28 08:47:52.056021 [PID 19088] tm31
Time taken for sqrt() is 1.00 nanoseconds (1.679867 ns).
Sum of square roots from 0 to 1000000000 is: 21081851051977.781250
2020-03-28 08:47:53.742383 [PID 19088; status 0x0000]  -  1.686362s  -  tm31
gcc -O3 -g -I../inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes tm41.c -o tm41 -L../lib -lsoq 
2020-03-28 08:47:53.908285 [PID 19099] tm41
Time taken for cbrt() is 7.00 nanoseconds (6.697999 ns).
Sum of cube roots from 0 to 1000000000 is: 749999999499.628418
2020-03-28 08:48:00.613357 [PID 19099; status 0x0000]  -  6.705072s  -  tm41
g++ -O3 -g -I../inc  -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror tm43.cpp -o tm43 -L../lib -lsoq 
2020-03-28 08:48:00.817975 [PID 19110] tm43
Time taken for cbrt() is 7.00 nanoseconds (6.614539 ns).
Sum of cube roots from 0 to 1000000000 is: 749999999499.628418
2020-03-28 08:48:07.438298 [PID 19110; status 0x0000]  -  6.620323s  -  tm43
gcc -O3 -g -I../inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes tm59.c -o tm59 -L../lib -lsoq 
2020-03-28 08:48:07.598344 [PID 19121] tm59
Time taken for fabs() is 1.00 nanoseconds (1.114822 ns).
Sum of absolute values from 0 to 1000000000 is: 499999999067108992.000000
2020-03-28 08:48:08.718672 [PID 19121; status 0x0000]  -  1.120328s  -  tm59
g++ -O3 -g  -I../inc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror tm61.cpp -o tm61 -L../lib -lsoq 
2020-03-28 08:48:08.918745 [PID 19132] tm61
Time taken for fabs() is 2.00 nanoseconds (1.117780 ns).
Sum of absolute values from 0 to 1000000000 is: 499999999067108992.000000
2020-03-28 08:48:10.042134 [PID 19132; status 0x0000]  -  1.123389s  -  tm61
g++ -O3 -g  -I../inc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror tm73.cpp -o tm73 -L../lib -lsoq 
2020-03-28 08:48:10.236899 [PID 19143] tm73
Time taken for cbrt() is 0.00 nanoseconds (0.000004 ns).
Cube root is: 215.443462
2020-03-28 08:48:10.242322 [PID 19143; status 0x0000]  -  0.005423s  -  tm73
$
```

I've run the programs many times; the times above are representative of what I got each time.  There are a number of conclusions that can be drawn:

- `sqrt()` (1.7 ns) is quicker than `cbrt()` (6.7 ns).
- `fabs()` (1.1 ns) is quicker than `sqrt()` (1.7 ns).
- However, `fabs()` gives a moderate approximation to the time taken with loop overhead and conversion from `int` to `double`.
- When the result of `cbrt()` is not used, the compiler eliminates the loop.
- When compiled with the C++ compiler, the code with from the question removes the loop altogether, leaving only the calls to `time()` to be measured.  The result printed by `clk_elapsed_us()` is the time taken to execute the code between `clk_start()` and `clk_stop()` in seconds with microsecond resolution — `0.000004` is 4 microseconds elapsed time.   The value is marked in `ns` because when the loop executes one billion times, the elapsed time in seconds also represents the time in nanoseconds for one loop — there are a billion nanoseconds in a second.
- The times reported by `timecmd` are consistent with the times reported by the programs.  There is the overhead of starting the process (`fork()` and `exec()`) and the I/O in the process that is included in the times reported by `timecmd`.
- Although not shown, the timings with `clang` and `clang++` (instead of GCC 9.3.0) are very comparable, though the `cbrt()` code takes about 7.5 ns per iteration instead of 6.7 ns.  The timing differences for the others are basically noise.

<sup>*The number suffixes are all 2-digit primes.  They have no other significance except to keep the different programs separate.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathan Leffler commented, compiler can optimize your C / c++ code. If the C code just loops from 0 to 1000 w/o doing anything with the counter `i` (I mean, w/o printing it or using the intermediate values in any other operation, indexes, etc), compiler may **not** even create the assembly code that corresponds to that loop. Possible arithmetic operations will even be pre-computed. For the code below;

```
int foo(int x) {
    return x * 5;
}

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int y = foo(x);
    ...
    ...
}
```

it is not surprising for the compiler to generate just two lines of assembly code (the compiler may even by-pass calling the function foo and generate an inline instruction) for function `foo`:

```
mov $15, %eax
; compiler will not bother multiplying 5 by 3
; but just move the pre-computed '15' to register
ret
; and then return
```